# show only beamertemplate{footline} not beamertemplate{headline} in all my frame in class beamer

Tags: beamer, header-footer, frame-title

I would like to show the

```
beamertemplate{ footline }
```

not

```
beamertemplate{ headline }
```

in all my frame in class `beamer`

but when i use

```
plain
```

I lost the footline in my frame

```
\documentclass{beamer}
 \usetheme{Warsaw}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,french]{babel}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{pifont}

\begin{document}
\section[Section I]{}
\begin{frame}[plain]
\frametitle{title}

\end{frame}
\section[Section II]{}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{title}

\end{frame}
\section[Section III]{}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\begin{document}
\section{Section I}

{%
    \setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
    \vspace*{-1.04cm}
    \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{title}
    \end{frame}
}

\section{Section II}

    \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{title}
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]